# PhoneGap Experience

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, cordova

Can I believe that, I can develop an app with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript and then compile it with PhoneGap for Android, iOS and Win Phone 7?

Does this work?

Comment: I ask, if that is sure that when i develp a Web App (HTML5) that PhoneGap creates me Apps for Android and iOs, ...

Answer (score 9):

PhoneGap's platform support is quite well documented:
http://www.phonegap.com/about/features/

For the most part, yes ... though the individual feature support is still coming up in some platforms. *edit: previously this mentioned that windows phone wasn't supported yet, this is now a fully supported platform :-) http://phonegap.com/2011/12/20/phonegap-for-windows-phone-getting-started/*

As far as how to create the packages for each individual platform, by default if doing things locally you'll have to integrate the phonegap bits into a project and compile it using that platform's build tools manually. However, they are working on a service called PhoneGap Build that will automatically create packages for each platform on your behalf:
https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 5):

For readers from the future, full Windows Phone 7 support in PhoneGap is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 support will, hopefully, come later this year. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does and you should check out their PhoneGap Build which is a cloud offering.  It's an open source product and the available technical documentation is currently growing.

Here's a primer on the topic.

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B006X4A1TM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006X4A1TM)

Jan - March 2012 will see more books published by various authors.  There's an in-depth book being published in March 2012 so stay tuned for more learning sources.

Answer (score 0):

phonegap works -> like a HTML file run on browser's phone..
but toolbar browser not show, because phonegap use webkit the browser,so you can create a Android, Windows phone,IPhone app using html,css, js..
for complete documentation visit in [phonegap.com](http://www.phonegap.com)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes it does work. Also you could use Xamarin